# How to automate EC2 instance startup and ssh connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

At the moment I connect with the following step manually:

1. Open EC2-Instance web
2. Under **Actions** -> **Instance State** click **Start**
3. Look at **Connect** tab
4. Manually copy the ssh command e.g.:

   `ssh -i "mykey.pem" ubuntu@ec2-13-112-241-333.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

What's the best practice so that I can streamline these stems through command line in my local computer? So that I can just use one command.

Comment: You can use ec2 command line. Create a batch or shell script. The following can be done though commands: start, check state whether running or pending, get autoallocated dns name. Then you can fire ssh on the dns. Please check the manual for the exact commands. I use java, but you have many options.

Answer (score 3):

An approach with [awscli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/index.html) would be

```
# Start the instance
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-xxxxxxxxxxx

status=0

# Wait for the instance until the 2/2 checks are passed
while [ $status -lt 2]
do
    status=`aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-ids  i-xxxxxxxxxxx --filters Name="instance-status.reachability,Values=passed" | grep  '"Status": "passed"' | wc -l`
    # add sleep time 
done

#  Associate an Elastic IP if already have one allocated (skip if not reqd)
aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id i-xxxxxxxxxxx --public-ip elastic_ip

#  Get the Public DNS, (If the instance has only PrivateIp, grep "PrivateIpAddress")
public_dns=`aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-xxxxxxxxxxx | grep "PublicDnsName" | head -1 | awk -F: '{print $2}' | sed 's/\ "//g;s/",//g'`

ssh -i key.pem username@public_dns
```

Comment: Or, assign an **Elastic IP Address** and to keep the same IP address even after the instance is stopped/started (additional charges apply).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, Not sure whether the OP needs it. Added it to the answer, someone might find it useful.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein How do you add *Elastic IP Address* to franklinsijo's code?

Comment: @neversaint It is added

Comment: The code would simply be: Start instance, wait for it to start, then ssh to it. By the way, waiting for a Status Check of "Passed" is probably waiting too long, since the instance is normally running well before the status check is complete. I'd wait for State = Running, then try to connect. Just retry if it doesn't work.

Comment: @franklinsijo: Is there a way I can make it automatically mount to my S3-bucket?

Comment: @neversaint I have never tried that,but I believe you have to do that after ssh-ing into the instance.